# How to reset the dropdown button in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dropdownbutton

I have a dropdown button which works fine when I visit the page(having the button) first time  but whenever i revisit the page containing the dropdown button, the previously selected value appears rather than the hint text which i want to appear every time the page is visited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dropdown button has a property **value** where we specify our variable to get the selected value. Before moving to the next screen you can set back the default value to it and it should work.

Comment: thanks worked just fine but i also had to use that variables value in the next page so i created another variable to hold that value, all in all task completed :)

Comment: Yes, it's not an optimal solution but works fine. Glad it worked for you. If it helped you then could you please accept the answer, that would be great.